# Resize custom UIBarButtonItem in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to add custom UIBarButtonItem in the navigation of my app.
With the following code, I managed to add one

```
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10)
    rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburgerMenuIcon"), for: .normal)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)                  target: nil, action: nil)
```

but it looks like the rightButton.frame is not working as it doesn't change the button's dimensions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From iOS 11 Navigation bar come up with Autolayout so frame setting may not work. Use the following code

```
let rightButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
rightButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 10, height: 10)
rightButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"hamburgerMenuIcon"), for: .normal)

let menuBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightButton)
let currWidth = menuBarItem.customView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
currWidth?.isActive = true
let currHeight = menuBarItem.customView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
currHeight?.isActive = true
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = menuBarItem
```